# Rename object in R using contents of string object

Tags: r, rename, naming

I want to change the name of an object to another name, which is contained in a string object.

Specifically, I want to change the `mtcars` to `mtcars_new_name`. I started by creating an object called `name_object` using the code below:

`name_object <- "mtcars_new_name"`

I then tried to put the `mtcars` object into the first element of the `name_object`, but it didn't work:

```
> name_object[1] <- mtcars
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8,  :
  provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables
```

This didn't not produce the desired result, and I don't know how to cure this. Please advice.

Comment: Are you doing the reverse when your description is `I want to change the mtcars to mtcars_new_name`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, which just reflects my own weakness with R. What I'm really trying to do is get the text that is in the ```name_object``` object ("mtcars_new_name") to become the name of the ```mtcars``` data, so when I call ```mtcars_new_name``` object I get the ```mtcars``` data.

Comment: There is some discussion about this. The short answer is you can not rename an r Object

Comment: @Mel I think there was a confusion in your post.  I am asuming that you want `rm(list = new_object)` and then `name_object <- "mtcars_new_name"; assign(name_object, mtcars)`

Comment: @akrun, I think that should work okay. Will test it and let you know.

Comment: I think you are looking for some kind of `swap` function that changes the value from the object created